# Finding duplicate values over multiple databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, duplicates

There are multiple (mysql) databases running under 1 website. 1 database per registered account.

I'm looking for duplicate records in each contacts-table.

This is what i have for finding duplicates inside only 1 database:

```
SELECT COUNT(contacts.email), contacts.email, contacts.state, contacts.source,
FROM shard_40000006.contacts 
LEFT JOIN shard_40000006.optin ON optin.email=contacts.email 
GROUP BY contacts.email
HAVING COUNT(contacts.email) > 1;
```

The query i need searches for duplicates over shard_40000001, shard_40000002, shard_40000003, .. shard_40999999

Comment: You must have *a lot of users* to manage it you want to set up (almost) 10 million databases! To me it seems likely that by revising your database architecture you can "simplify your life" significantly ...

Comment: I'm dealing with a legacy project here, but this is irrelevant for my question @cars10m ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic tsql.

```
declare @sqltext nvarchar(max) = N''
declare @parameter varchar(max) = 'define what you want to search here'
select @sqltext += '
SELECT COUNT(contacts.email), contacts.email, contacts.state, contacts.source,
FROM '+name+'.dbo.contacts 
LEFT JOIN '+name+'.dbo.optin ON optin.email=contacts.email 
GROUP BY contacts.email
HAVING COUNT(contacts.email) > 1'
FROM sys.databases
WHERE OBJECT_ID(QUOTENAME(name) + '.dbo.prac_nag', 'U') IS NOT NULL -- will return only if the table exists
print @sqltext
-- once your review the output, uncomment out below
--exec sp_executesql @sqltext
```

I just put refernce code. i didn't test this code.